# Switch windows using windows key + # shortcuts by window not app? Also show numbers on taskbar?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-11, taskbar, autohotkey

You can use the keyboard to switch programs in Windows 11, for example <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> goes to the second app on the taskbar, and <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd> goes to the second window of the third app. But it is a big pain to (1) guess/count to get each app on the taskbar's shortcut number and (2) press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + that number multiple times to get to the right window in each program. Solution on my personal computer:

1. Winearo Tweaker to restore Windows 10 taskbar so I can use:
2. 7+ Taskbar Tweaker to ungroup programs for the purpose of the keyboard shortcuts
3. 7+ Taskbar Numberer to see the number of each window (a little number icon overlayed on each taskbar item)
4. Change Windows 11 to dark theme so I can see the numbers

Unfortunately my work IT department won't allow either 7+ program. Is there any other way to do this? I can use AutoHotkey, but I don't know if it can get the order and width of windows on the taskbar. If not using position on the taskbar, is there any good way to switch windows with the keyboard? I do it a ton so multi-step shortcuts such as <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> are a bad option. Maybe something like Task View I can activate with one key, with a number next to each window which you can type to activate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pin programs to the taskbar and move them in a specific slot, so you always know which key combination is for a given program.

If you press the key combination while the program is active, it will switch to the program (otherwise it opens a new instance). If the program spawns multiple windows and creates a group, you can switch between windows inside that group by pressing the key combination multiple times in a row.

With this knowledge, you can actually create an auto-hotkey script that switches to the 2nd or 3rd, etc... window from a group by pressing its keyboard shortcut key multiple times.

For example, lets say the window in question is placed on the 3rd slot in your taskbar, you could map WIN+F1 to press WIN+3 once, WIN+F2 to press WIN+3 twice and WIN+F3 to press WIN+3 three times.

Comment: Interesting, so using all the F keys I could have 3 programs with up to 4 windows each (12/3) or 4 programs with up to 3 windows each. Not the universal solution I ideally want, but worth trying out.

Comment: You're not even bound to F keys, but I doubt you will be having more than 12 options anyway.

Comment: Oh yeah, I realized of course I don't need F keys for the first window of any program. I'm thinking F1-F4 for Outlook windows #2-#5, F5-F8 for Excel, F9-F11 for Teams, and F12 for VS Code window #2. Nice!

Comment: Hm, so I can't get it to work in AHK 1.1. `#f1:: #1` does not work for some reason, it just types a 1. Seems like maybe a # hotkey cannot send another # hotkey?

Comment: Hm, it seems like sometimes it works and sometimes not, but I can't figure out why. Even if I don't change the ahk code, sometimes it works and sometimes not...

Comment: Maybe you need to add a slight delay in between keystrokes.

Comment: Yes that worked, seems like maybe having the windows key held down while sending the windows key makes it not work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use AutoHotkey, you don't need to adhere to the rules of the system for switching windows.

I'd use something like this:

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v1.1

        ; === auto-execute section ===  (top of the script)

; create a group of each program:  
GroupAdd, explorer, ahk_class CabinetWClass
GroupAdd, notepad, ahk_class Notepad
GroupAdd, msedge, ahk_exe msedge.exe
; ...

            RETURN   ; === end of auto-execute section ===

; Press Win+Number to run a new instance of each program: 
#1::Run explorer
#2::Run notepad
#3::Run msedge

; Press Ctrl+Win+Number to 
; activate the window of each program if their number is 1, 
; to activate the next window if their number is 2 
; or to create a menu if their number is greater than 2: 
^#1::activate_group("explorer")
^#2::activate_group("notepad")
^#3::activate_group("msedge")

activate_group(group){
    WinGet, number_of_windows, count, ahk_group %group%
    If (number_of_windows = 0) 
        return
    If (number_of_windows = 1) || (number_of_windows = 2)
        GroupActivate, %group%, R
    else
        Menu(group)
}   
    
    Menu(group){
    Menu, Windows, Add
    Menu, Windows, deleteAll
    WinGet, id, list, ahk_group %group%
    Loop, %id%
    {
        this_ID := id%A_Index%
        WinGetTitle, title, ahk_id %this_ID%
        WinGet, Path, ProcessPath, ahk_id %this_ID%     
        Menu, Windows, Add, %title%%A_Tab%%this_ID%, AktivateWindow
        Try 
            Menu, Windows, Icon, %title%%A_Tab%%this_ID%, %Path%    
        Catch 
            Menu, Windows, Icon, %title%%A_Tab%%this_ID%, %A_WinDir%\System32\SHELL32.dll, 3, 0 
    }
    Menu, Windows, Show
}

AktivateWindow:
    ID := StrSplit(A_ThisMenuItem, A_Tab).2
    WinActivate, ahk_id %ID%
return
```

Comment: Cool, yeah I got it to work. It's still significantly more keystrokes than a two-key combination, but worth messing around with...

Comment: You can replace `Ctrl+Win+Number` with `Alt+Number`(!1::, !2:: etc) for a two-key combination.